# Delete object behind parameter inside an function

Tags: javascript

Here an code example:

```
var testFunction = function(x) {
    delete(x); //x = null
}
var array = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
$.each(array, function(e, e1) {
  testFunction(e1);
}
```

I'd like to delete an element out of the array inside an function. It would be possible to delete it with an index ( `delete(array[1])`  ) but I can't do this in my case because the delete function should be later inside an on-Button-Press function (one button per Array-Element) (not like in the example) and the index is dynamically changing.
The currently function would delete/set the x variable null and it won't affect the variable inside the array.

Is there a way to delete the referred object behind a variable? Maybe with `.getObject()` or something like this?

Edit:
Full example:

```
var createButton = function(object, placeThere) {
    var oButton1 = new sap.ui.commons.Button({
    text : ("Delete " + object.value),
    });
    //do some more not relevant stuff here

    oButton1.attachPress(function() {
        delete(object); /*deleteObjectOutOfArray*/
    }
    oButton1.placeAt(placeThere);  
}

var array = [new Object(), new Object(), new Object()]; //array filled with objects with diffrent variables like for example value
$each (array, function(e1, e2) {
    createButton(e2, "nameOfDiv");
}
```

Comment: `delete function should be later inside an on-Button-Press function (one button per Array-Element) (not like in the example)` So maybe provide relevant example of what you are after?

Comment: Edited a full example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Declare array first, so following code can refer to it
var array = [new Object(), new Object(), new Object()];

var createButton = function(object, placeThere) {
    // then after not relevant stuff:
    oButton1.attachPress(function() {
        array.splice(array.indexOf(object), 1); // this removes object from array
    }
    // rest of code
}
```